# getintent().getStringExtra() shows null when pass data

Tags: android-intent, android-activity

First activity Code is below:

```
 String col1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
 Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, chat.class); 
 i.putExtra("nam",col1.toString());
 startActivity(i);
```

Second activity Code is below:

```
 String fName = getIntent().getStringExtra("nam");
 Toast.makeText(this, fName+" Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

it shows null..why?

Comment: Have you checked that `c.getColumnIndex("name")` has a value??

Comment: Your code seems OK, col1 it is not null because col1.toString() would throw a NullPointerException. ¿Maybe field value is "null" like a String?

Comment: Add logging to your code (or use debugger) to verify that `col1` actually contains what you think it contains. The code you've posted looks just fine.

Comment: Yes, I checked it but not working David Wasser..